# Munchkins Ruling of destroy item with highest bonus

Tags: munchkin

On the table there are 2 items giving bonus of 4 and 5,  the one with 4 is used and the one with 5 is carried and not used.

The card **"Lose the card that gives you the biggest bonus"**, does it destroy the 5 or 4 bonus card?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Items that aren't in use don't give you any bonus.